# How to Get the "Link A" of an article in Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla, geturl, url-link

I would like to know what is the code to get links "Link A" or "Link B" found in the panel to create an article, maybe you can enlighten me.

Image for example
http://goo.gl/v9jXU2

Comment: Get the urls field and then json_decode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In article model there is a function called getItem($pk) where $pk is article id.

File: `components\com_content\models\article.php`

Call this function with passing article id. this will return all article related data.

In result you can find links  "Link A" or "Link B" in urls variable like below:

`$result = $model->getItem($articleId);`

`$result->urls` contains information related to links  "Link A" or "Link B". json_decode this data and use accordingly.